# Junit: Writing Unit test cases for Removing Student from a Group

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests

Am testing a feature `removeStudent(Student s, Group g)` where expected behaviour is that if `Group` is empty, calling `removeStudent` will do nothing.

How do we test this behaviour?

Here are some methods:

```
private final Map<Group, Set<Student>> studentsInGroup = new HashMap<>();

public void removeStudent(Student s, Group g) {

    Collection<Student> students = getStudentsInGroup(g);

    studentsInGroup.remove(s);
}

public Collection<Student> getStudentsInGroup(Group g) {

    Collection<Student> students = studentsInGroup.get(g);
    if (students == null) {
        students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    return students;
}
```

Am able to write just one test case:

```
 @Test
public void testRemoveStudentFromEmptyGroup() {
    // have created a Student: FRED and a Group: ADMINS
    // Have not created any mapping for Group and ADMINS, so currently getStudentsInGroup(ADMINS) will return an empty Set<Student>
    service.removeStudent(FRED, ADMINS);
    assertTrue("ADMINS group is empty. Do nothing", service.getStudentsInGroup(ADMINS).size() == 0);
}
```

Is this a correct case to test the requirement? What more test can I add to this?

Comment: More or less correct.  You should probably also try adding that student and group first, to make sure it really does remove a student in a group.  Plus several more iterations of the idea.

Comment: Yeah. That works. The idea is to think of more test cases around removing student from empty group should simply be ignored.